# Error in Creating Package

Tags: magento

I created a package based on Magento ver-1.6. When I upload that package/extension through Magento-connect it through the following error. I googled and didn't got clear idea.

```
CONNECT ERROR: The 'local' channel is not installed. Please use the MAGE shell script to install the 'local' channel.
```

All other extensions are installed properly when we installed through Magento-Connect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [packaging manual](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/packaging_a_magento_extension_in_1.5) the channel should be "community", not "local".

The channel is not the same as the pool, which would be the folder you put a module in.

Answer (score 1):

You should use these commands in your Magento root folder:

```
chmod 777 mage
./mage mage-setup .
```